# Three.js add static background to demo-earth.html?

Tags: three.js, edit, demo

Three.js is awesome! I'm having trouble adding a static background scene to earth.html demo. I've tried using CSS, this code

```
            var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'rainier.jpg' );
            var backgroundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture

                }));
            backgroundMesh .material.depthTest - false;
            backgroundMesh .material.depthWrite - false;

            //Background Scene

            var backgroundScene - new THREE.Scene();
            var backgroundCamera - new THREE.Camera();
            backgroundScene .add(backgroundCamera );
            backgroundScene .add(backgroundMesh );
```

to no avail! So far I've changed the texture of the sphere successfully. When I add the code above it displays the background and no sphere? This is my first experience with THREE.js. I started with modifying a demo to get the feel for the syntax and operations. Any help would be greatly appreciated!